# Remove commas except last one w preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

My head is spinning, I tried to do this on my own, but cant figure it out. so once again I will turn to your guys knowledge.

These all are my possible my strings:

```
My head is spinning with, pregreplace
My head is spinning, with, pregreplace
My head is, spinning, with, pregreplace
My head, is, spinning, with, pregreplace
```

(Notice commas in above strings)

I want to have all "preg-replaced" / "string-replaced" with only one comma at the end.(Just like displayed on first example)

My head is spinning with, pregreplace

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: `strrpos`, `substr`, `str_replace`, that's all.

Comment: Both works great, I will select answer in next 10 minutes. I noticed on my data, that I also have multi lines ie like this:My head is spinning with, pregreplace (Shoot I cant edit multi lines here... but basically need to make it single line as well with this same script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a "positive lookahead" like this:

`,(?=.*,)`

The lookahead is the part in parens.  It basically says "only replace this comma if there's another comma later in the string.

The code would look like this:

```
echo preg_replace('/,(?=.*,)/', '', $str);
```

I tested this with RegexBuddy to confirm it works:

[image]

Comment: you're missing pattern delimiters in the first ``preg_replace`` argument.  or are they optional these days? am i showing my age here?  otherwise, +1.

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_replace( '/,/', '', $my_string, preg_match_all( '/,/', $my_string) - 1);
```

The above should do what you need.

Comment: Would `strrpos` be a more-efficient method than `preg_match_all` in this case?

Comment: Wish I could give 2 answer credits... I gave you a bump anyhow... Thanks

Comment: @ColinO'Dell Yes, I originally wrote the solution using the string functions, but since the request was specifically for using preg_replace I provided that solution.